# Wordpress website stops working for a particular IP after updating a page

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

Weirdest problem ever. I use wordpress (last version) for my website and I use WP-bakery page builder. It has worked without problems for years. All my plugins are updated to the latest version, except WP bakery page builder because i'm not paying for it.

Today, i decided to update the website, and I go to the contact page of my website and change 1 word in the page and click "update". The website ends up showing a "timeout" and the website stopped working.

```
"This site can’t be reached.  Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"
```

In opera the error is DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Then I tried with a VPN and the website works, so I try to update the page again and "timeout" again and the website is down

Then I changed the VPN ip again and my website is working on that new IP. I try to change a blog post, no problem, I add new pages with the testimonial plugin and no problem, then, thinking that everything is ok, i go to the contact page again and i change 1 word and boom... time out and the website is dead for that IP

Now I run out of VPNs to test and I can't access my website anymore, but this problem is very strange.

I tried https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/ and that website says that my site is up, but i can't access it anymore due to this change that produced the same awful result 3 or 4 times.

Who knows about this mysterious issue and a potential solution?

The following is the list of plugins i use:

1. Akismet
2. Contact Form 7
3. Cookie Notice
4. Google Analytics for WordPress by MonsterInsights:
5. Hello Dolly
6. Hide Featured Image:
7. Jivo Chat
8. Maintenance and WP Maintenance mode:
9. PageBuilder by Site Origin and WPBakery page builder:
10. Read More without refresh and WP Show More:
11. ShortPixel image optimizer:
12. Show Hide Author:
13. Simple Custom CSS:
14. Slider Revolution:
15. ThemesFlat by Themesflat.com:
16. WP Downgrade | Specific core version:

Comment: please list any security or cache related plugins that you have installed

Comment: i added all the plugins used on my website @Scriptable

Comment: Plugins look ok. Have you checked your hosting? could be becoming overloaded

Comment: nothing has changed... no new hosting

Comment: sorry im not suggesting you have changed anything or its a new host. alot of wordpress sites run on shared hosting and alot of wordpress sites are also targeted by bots to try and gain access to your website for malicious purposes. Many of my websites login pages are constantly under fire, putting heavy load on the server running it. I would suggest checking your servers resources and logs, and see if there is anything unusual happening

Comment: I had to install security plugins to stop constant attacks on my websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it happened, but I discovered that a rule of modsecurity blocked my IP whenever I attempted to update my page... Seems to be a security thing with wordpress to avoid attacks... This shows up in the server log.

To solve it I removed the rule for my website... which may cause some security issues, but who cares about security.

But I don't know where this blocking comes from...